# System.in.available() allways return a zero in windows 8

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, macos

I'm trying to bring over my code from a mac to a windows 8 environment.
I'm using eclipse and was able to import the project ok. but 
when the code runs on my windows computer `System.in.available()` will allways return a `zero`.

I want my program to keep looping until a key is press.  This is what I have now, which works in apple but not windows in eclipse environment

```
} while(mEnd.compareTo("exit")!=0);
```

Comment: edit your question, and try to paste all the code, not only the `while`line. maybe the error could be before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the command line directly in an eclipse terminal window, this approach can help:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

And use this `BufferedReader` to read lines rather than directly from `System.in`:

```
mEnd = br.readLine();
```